# Jquery mobile Fixed header/footers on Blackberry

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am creating a Cordova app using JqueryMobile, everything seems to be working fine on Android both device and simulators.

With blackberry the issue i've (in simulator so far) is that the header and footer are not showing (both with  data-position="fixed").
The strange part is that on top (and bottom) of the screen the the 'space' is like 'reserved'.

Also, to make it even more strange on that page there is an 'input' that if I ever click on it the header shows! but when it loses the focus the header is back to hidden!

Any ideas? This issue is pretty much blowing my mind today

Comment: After some other testing seems like the  problem is the fixed positioning. By removing it it just displays ok. Too bad because keeping it just for Android would be nice (since it seems to work as intended)

Comment: Hi Dennis, you should try to get you hands on a real device, the simulators are inconsistent. Which OS are you trying?